# How do I send sms like those are sent after a money transaction is done in banks from my android application

Tags: java, php, android, sms, payment

In my android application,each user gets 100 Rs. when he registers.
Now in one of the activity if a user firstly clicks on a button say "V1" and the payment is successful then my app should send sms something like - "30 Rs. deducted, balance is 70 Rs." to the logged in user on his mobile number (stored in a users database) if the payment is successful.
Again if he clicks any other button say "V3" and the payment is successful then it should send a sms- "30 Rs. deducted, balance is 40 Rs." 
How can I do this? Also where can I store the amount which user is balance after the first click, similarly after the second click and so on ? Any suggestions or advices will be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: whats this got to do with php?

Comment: If I am not using PHP to send sms then what can be an alternative for this ?

Comment: i assumed you would send it from the phone itself

Comment: No not from the device. My app should automatically do that once the payment is successful in the activity. Like we receive sms after an online transaction, in the same way it has to be done.

Comment: ok then sign up to a sms gateway, and use their api.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you just mentioned ? Any link for suggestion ?\